# If the measure theoretic boundary is closed must it coincide with the topological boundary?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Int{Int}\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}$Suppose $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a set of finite perimeter and suppose that the measure theoretic boundary $\partial^*E=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus(\Int(E)\cup \Ext(E))$ is closed, where $\Int(E)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathscr{L}^n(E\cap B_r(x))}{\omega_n r^n}=1\}$ and $\Ext(E)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\,\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathscr{L}^n(E\cap B_r(x))}{\omega_n r^n}=0\}$. Is it true that then there is a Borel set $\tilde{E}$ with $\mathscr{L}^n(\tilde{E}\mathbin\Delta E)=0$ and $\partial^*E=\partial \tilde{E}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed true; you can find the answer to your question in Francesco Maggi's book for example, by combining Proposition 12.9 and Remark 15.3. I'll paraphrase the argument.

Let $E \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ be a Caccioppoli set, and $\mu_E$ be its Gauss–Green measure. Then $\partial^* E \subset \operatorname{spt} \mu_E$, and as the support is closed, one has
\begin{equation}
\overline{\partial^* E} = \operatorname{spt} \mu_E.
\end{equation}
Now, said proposition gives the existence of a Borel set $\tilde{E}$ so that $\mathcal{H}^n(E \triangle \tilde{E}) = 0$ and $\partial \tilde{E} = \operatorname{spt} \mu_{\tilde{E}}$. But then
\begin{equation}
\partial \tilde{E} = \operatorname{spt} \mu_{\tilde{E}} = \operatorname{spt} \mu_E = \overline{\partial^* E} = \partial^* E.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is essentially true, if you allow the conclusion to hold up to sets of measure zero. You can even choose $\widetilde{E} $ to be open. See Lemma 6.2 of [De Rosa, Kolasiński, and Santilli - Uniqueness of Critical Points of the Anisotropic Isoperimetric Problem for Finite Perimeter Sets](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00205-020-01562-y).

Answer (score 2):

I have found that an answer to my question is contained in Maggi's book "Sets of finite perimeter and geometric variational problems" at page 127 (Proposition $12.19$). This is in the same spirit of the result Longyearbyen referred to in his answer but is more precise since it gives a true equality, not one that holds up to a set of measure zero (using that, as proven in Remark $15.3$ of the same book, $\overline{\partial^*E}=spt(\mu_{ E})$ ).

Comment: I just noticed that you found the answer on your own, and using the same reference... Small world I guess! I'll leave mine up for now so people don't have to get the book out, but if you want to copy the paraphrased argument into yours I'd be happy to delete it too.

Comment: I am happy to accept your answer and leave mine as it is since you provided more details.

Comment: Cool, thanks - I liked the question, by the way!